# Typescript Record generic get type of current object

Tags: typescript, generics

Sorry that the title is not good, but I do not know how to place the question
I have these types

```
export type InnerEventObject = {
  id: string | number;
  a: number; 
};

export type EventObject<T> = InnerEventObject & T;

type CombinedData<T> = Readonly<
  Record<string, Readonly<{ data: EventObject<T>[] }>>
>;

export function defineConfig<D extends CombinedData<InnerEventObject>>(
  props: Record<
    keyof D,
    {
      cell: (event: TODO) => void;
    }
  >
) {
  return props;
}
```

And this Implementation

```
import { defineConfig, type EventObject } from "../types";
type Data1 = {
  b: string;
};
type Data2 = {
  c: string;
};
const data1: EventObject<Data1>[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    a: 1,
    b: "string",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    a: 2,
    b: "string",
  },
];

const data2: EventObject<Data2>[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    a: 1,
    c: "string",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    a: 2,
    c: "string",
  },
];

export const data = {
  data1: { data: data1 },
  data2: {
    data: data2,
  },
} as const;

export const config = defineConfig<typeof data>({
  data1: {
    cell: (event) => {}, //event should be EventObject<Data1>
  },
  data2: {
    cell(event) {}, //event should be EventObject<Data2>
  },
});
```

What should the TODO type be so that the callback prop event knows that it is the event of the current property so in data1 event is **EventObject<Data1>** and in data2 it is **EventObject<Data2>**

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NdJ0YW) meet your needs? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?